# What is this so called "multiply-divide trick" used below for calculating the integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am working through the exercises from [this page](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/mtold/exd/eed2.htm). To solve exercise 3 they use a trick they call the "multiply-divide trick" to get $\int \frac{1}{\sin(2x)} \; dx = \int \frac{\sin(2x)}{1-\cos^2(2x)} \; dx$.

They have a short explanation of the "multiply divide trick":

> Imagine that we have the expression $3x + 5$, but we would prefer to have the coefficent $7$ at $x$ and do not want other terms with $x$ there. This last requirement prevents us from adding and subtracting, but we can do this: $3x + 5 = 3⋅(x + 5/3) = (3/7)⋅(7x + 35/3)$.

However I don't get how this helps me with the integral above. So how do we get the integral equation above using the trick described here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that your integral, after the "trick", is **almost** of the form

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{1-f(x)^2}dx=\int\frac12\left(\frac{f'}{1-f}+\frac{f'}{1+f}\right)dx=\frac12\left(-\log|1-f|+\log|1+f|\right)+C=$$

$$=\log\sqrt{\frac{|1+f|}{|1-f|}} +C$$

and, thus, you can easily solve your integral

Comment: Thanks. What I don't understand is how we use the trick I described. I don't understand the trick itself, not how it helps. I don't understand how we get $\int \frac{sin(2x)}{1-cos^2(2x)}\;dx$ in the first place. After rereading my question now I see that I did not make this clear enough, sorry.

Comment: Just multiply the original expression by $\;\cfrac{\sin 2x}{\sin 2x}\;$ and then use the trigonometric Pythagoras Theorem: $\;\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\implies \sin^22x=1-\cos^22x\;$ . This kind of tricks are very common and sometimes pretty hlepful to solve this kind of trigonometric integrals !

Comment: very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This helps you because

$$\sin(2x) dx = -\frac{1}{2}d(\cos(2x))$$